# ": Error: Not found: 'dart:js'" in a Flutter Application

Tags: javascript, flutter, mobile-application

I am trying to call a Javascript function in a js file from the flutter "main.dart" but when I imported the JS library, I am getting the following error.

> : Error: Not found: 'dart:js'

The below picture link represents the error message.

The Error shown in the debug console

[image: 1]

Please help me to solve this issue, I tried everything which is already available.